# Nifi insert data to druid on docker

Tags: docker, apache-nifi, druid

I have 2 docker-containers installed in different servers

1. docker-druid
2. docker-NiFi

When I used NiFi to insert data to druid, I had this error:

[image: Nifi insert data to druid]

Do you have any ideas? How do this configuration for druid?

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

As you are using in your Reader/Writer controller services

**Schema Access Strategy** as **Use 'SchemaName' Property** then

Make sure you are having **schema.name** attribute associated with the **flowfile**.

To add the attribute use **Update Attribute** processor

add new property called
**schema.name** and value as **schema_name**

**Example:**

if you are using AvroSchemaRegistry to access the schema then the name of the schema will be your schema.name attribute value.

For more details refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/115311/convert-csv-to-json-avro-xml-using-convertrecord-p.html) link and look into configs of **UpdateAttribute** processor in the flow.

**Update:**

As per your sample data instead of using JsonPathReader use JsonTreeReader and JsonSetWriter controller services.

You are missing schema property in AvroSchemaRegistry controller service.

in AvroSchemaRegistry add **property** by clicking + sign at top right

**demo**

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "balances",
    "namespace": "nifi",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "submit_date",
        "type": ["null",
        "string"]
    },
    {
        "name": "request_type",
        "type": ["null",
        "string"]
    },
    {
        "name": "origin",
        "type": ["null",
        "string"]
    },{
        "name": "description",
        "type": ["null",
        "string"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Hi Shu, please see updated pictures, now after I done the steps as your suggestions it had new error "JSON Paths" is invalid because NO JSON Paths were specified

Comment: @ThuyLe, Is there any specific reason to use JsonPathReader controller service?.. if not use **JsonTreeReader Controller** service as this controller service **don't need to add any JSON path's** to be specified... for more reference to jsonpath reader https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.json.JsonPathReader/additionalDetails.html

Comment: Thank @Shu, I fig that error now new error when streaming data to druid. Please see the update question

Comment: Hi @Shu, **Update pictures**

insert data to druid -config and insert data to druid -config_1 and also error err insert data to druid


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXRTr.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzn6f.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcDTz.png